# Why th:maxlength does not limit the length to four characters

Tags: html, thymeleaf

```
<input class="form-control" th:type="number" th:maxlength="4" id="code" th:field="*{code}" th:value="${code}" />
```

On my HTML5 page the above input field prevents alphanumerical characters to be inputed, but does not limits the length to 4 characters.

How to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change input type "number" to "text"

`th:maxlength="4"` won't work on `th:type="number"` its only works on `th:type="text"`.

Answer (score 2):

No need to change the input type from number to text. The input type `number` doesn't have the `maxlength` attribute(See: [HTML DOM Input Number Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_number.asp)). Instead you should use `min` and `max` attributes. So your html should look like,

```
<input class="form-control" th:type="number" th:max="4" id="code" 
       th:field="*{code}" th:value="${code}" />
```

Now it will allow only to input numbers with a max value of 4.